# Gain edittext focus tapping next in soft keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have numerous edittexts inside a listview. I want to type in each of the edittexts one by one without having to scroll through the listview. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `android:nextFocusDown` param to specify which field you'd like to get focus when the user hits the enter key.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Tell me where to add this param? listview or edittext? and which enter key are you talking about?

Comment: Enter key in keypad ( i mean when you given this param to edittext on keypad it shows next button )